# limit $\lim_{x\to-2}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x - 6}+2}{x + 2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Can you help me with

$$\lim_{x\to-2}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x - 6}+2}{x + 2}$$

I've already tried to multiply at conjugate expression but I failed.

Comment: Please check that my edit is correct

Comment: Which conjugate expression you used, one wonders.

Comment: I had lots of ideas to help you, but they failed. Hard to tell the difference between this and nothing, isn't it?

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** 
$$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$$
Plug in $a=\sqrt[3]{x-6}$ and $b=2$...

Answer (score 6):

By the definition of the derivative we have
$$\lim_{x\to-2}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x - 6}+2}{x + 2}=\lim_{x\to-2}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x - 6}-\sqrt[3]{-2 - 6}}{x -(- 2)}=\left(\sqrt[3]{x - 6}\right)'\big|_{x=-2}=\frac{1}{12}$$

Comment: A valuable way+1

Comment: Nice work, as usual, Sami!

Answer (score 3):

Use L hopital rule$$\lim_{x\to-2}{\frac{1}{3}(x-6)^{\frac{-2}{3}}}={\frac{1}{3}\lim_{x\to-2}(x-6)^{\frac{-2}{3}}}=\lim_{x\to-2}{\frac{1}{3}(-8)^{\frac{-2}{3}}}=\frac{1}{12}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$  \lim_{x\to-2}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x - 6}+2}{x + 2}  \\$$

Let $ a= a=\sqrt[3]{x-6} $ and $ b=  {2} $ . Then $ a^3+b^3 = (a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$ . So $ a^3+b^3 = x+2 $  and $ a+b = \sqrt[3]{x - 6}+2 $  . So $ \frac{\sqrt[3]{x - 6}+2}{x + 2} $ = $  \frac{a+b}{a^3+b^3}$ = $\frac{1}{ a^2 - ab +b^2} $ . Hope so this helps a lot .

Here at $ x =-2 $ , the value of a is -2 . So at $  x= -2 $ the value of $ a^2-ab+b^2 = 4-(-2)2+4 = 12 $ .

So the ultimate value of  $$  \lim_{x\to-2}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x - 6}+2}{x + 2}  $$ is $ \frac{1}{12} $